# Не могу получить значение из реестра C#

Tags: c#, реестр

Создал функция которая проверяет есть ли параметр и если он есть то значение этого параметра записать в переменную. Но это не работает. В отладчике пишет что `Microsot.Win32.Registry.GetValue` возвращено `54.12.55`. То есть значение которые оно вернуло верное, но когда дело доходит до записи в переменную она возвращает `null`

```
if (Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\onliner","address", null) != null) 
{
    string test = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\onliner").GetValue("address").ToString();
}
else
{
    //nothing
}
```

Что я неправильно сделал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в пути. Если вы уже указали ключ `Registry.CurrentUser`, то в пути метода `.OpenSubKey()` не стоит его повторно прописывать.

Еще так как вы уже читаете значение при проверке, можно сразу его записать в переменную.

Вот рабочий вариант:

```cs
string test = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\onliner", "address", null)?.ToString();
if (test != null) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}
```

Comment: Немного улучшил ответ.

Comment: @aepot кстати, ты немного подпортил решение, хех. Я так понимаю, нужно было записать значение в переменную только в том случае, если это значение существует. А теперь, когда значение не существует,  будет возникать ошибка. Поэтому я бы еще изменил ответ и использовал бы try-catch. И в try была бы всего одна строчка: `string test = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\onliner", "address", null);`. А в catch сообщение об ошибке (MessageBox). Соответсвенно, если значение не существует, то ошибки не будет и в переменную ничего не запишется.

Comment: Для редактирования без проверки нужно 2000 репутации. В противном случае правка требует одобрения минимум двух участников с репутацией. Но ошибки здесь не будет, запишется просто `null` в переменную. Ой, и правда нашел косяк, ща поправлю...готово.

Comment: @aepot а что делает знак вопроса? Я так понимаю, если будет получен null, то из-за этого не будет проводиться конвертация в string, чтобы не было ошибки.

Comment: Верно. `string s = Method()?.ToString();` - примерно то же самое, что `string s; var data = Method(); if (data != null) s = data.ToString(); else s = null;` то есть `.ToString()` не будет вызван, если вернулся `null`. ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)).

Comment: Можно еще такой финт ушами, особенно полезно, когда нужно не `null`, а какое-то другое значение получить "по умолчанию". `string s = Method()?.ToString() ?? "(пусто)";` в этом случае вместо `null` запишется строка `(пусто)`. :)

Comment: Спасибо большое,работает